# Debug Aurelia webpack typescript application in VS2017

Tags: debugging, typescript, webpack, aurelia, visual-studio-2017

I did the following steps:

1. Downloaded Aurelia WebPack 2 typescript skeleton.
2. Installed all the node modules by running `yarn install`.
3. Opened the project folder in Visual Studio 2017.
4. Task Runner found `package.json`, and I can successfully start the task

Now I don't know how can I start the application and tell Visual Studio 2017 to debug it.

Please help.

**UPDATE**
This is what I see in the debug menu:

[image]

Comment: Have you gone through the steps in this blog post? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

Comment: Nope, will try it and post te answer. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I just tried the above link, but I don't have this settings in the debug drop-down. It seems this is only possible if you are debugging an ASP.Net Application, and I don't have an ASP.Net  application. I only have a folder with Aurelia skeleton in it.

Comment: Do you specifically want to use VS to debug and not your browser's dev tools? Is it unacceptable to manually run a command to serve the app?

Comment: Yes, I can now debug in web-browser and in webstorm, but I want to be able to develop and debug my application in VS2017. I have no problem with manually running a script, but then how to tell VS2017 to debug this application. It would be very good if I could pres F5 and run/debug the application.

Comment: It looks like debugging TypeScript in VS 2017 with Webpack is supported albeit in a finicky way: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/8516/debugging-typescript-in-vs-when-using-webpack.html

Comment: Yes I think the debug should work, the problem is that Visual studio does not know anything of this application, because there is no .csproj file, and no .sln file. I opened a folder containing my application. So vs does not know how to start this application and to attach a debugger  to it.

Comment: If you're ok with using .net core you could install SpaTemplates and have an aurelia project scaffolded for you. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

Comment: Oh I tried that too. It work as I can debug. But there are two things... 1. It does not aupport hotmodule reload. 2. Client does not want to use .Net Core.

Comment: The problem is that VS isn't actually building/running the code, unlike a .NET app and the IIS dev server. What's the reason behind wanting to _debug_ in VS? So you can debug your typescript files? (source maps let you do that with Chrome). I'm currently using VS Code to develop _and_ debug a typescript/aurelia/webpack app using the _Debugger For Chrome_ plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following highlighted lines and RunWebPack target to my .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="RunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
<!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in  
production mode -->
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config 
webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" />
  <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" />

  <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <DistFiles Include="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" 
Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
      <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Also open the Modules window during debugging, and check that whether it has more detailed information about which symbols met this issue.

Please also enable the Microsoft Symbol Servers under >ToolS->Options->Debugging, debug it again.

Comment: I don't have a .csproj file, I'm using VS2017 new command "Open folder" to pen my project folder.